# How can I return two fields using Linq on an object with more than two fields?

Tags: c#, linq

What I would like to do is something I find common in MySQL which is to select all of one field distinct, and a sum of another field in that data sub-set for each unique/distinct result.

Following should replicate something simple to use in order to see the type of data I mean :

```
public class Stock {
   public int id {get;set;}
   public int count {get;set;}
   public string location {get;set;}
   public Stock() { }
}

public class Foo {

   public void Bar() {
        List<Stock> Stocks = new List<Stock>()
        {
            new Stock
            {
                id = 137829,
                count = 5,
                location = "Ottawa"
            },
            new Stock
            {
                id = 137829,
                count = 27,
                location = "Toronto"
            },
            new Stock
            {
                id = 137830,
                count = 8,
                location = "Toronto"
            }

        };

        var result = Stocks.DistincyBy( s => s.id);
   }
}
```

What I would like to store in `result` is as follows (using this code as an example. the real project the structure is more complex).

- id = 137829, count = 32
- id = 137830, count = 8

I know I can use `.Sum()`, but in this scenario I wish to sum where one field is distinct. How can this be achieved (i prefer my Linq to be inline syntax rather than sql style querying)

Comment: What's the difference from using `GroupBy` + `Sum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GroupBy` to get the distinct groupings, then `Select` into your objects. For example:

```
var result = Stocks.GroupBy(s => s.Id).Select(g => new 
{
   Id = g.Key,
   Count = g.Sum(i => i.Count)
};
```

Better would be to create a named class to select into, but the syntax would be very similar.

Comment: How can this be used on dynamic enumerable ?  `IEnumerable<dynamic> result = auction.GroupBy(s => s.item).Select(g => new
            {
                Id = g.Key,
                Count = g.Sum(i => i.buyout)
            };`  results in a nesting issue where `i.item` doesn't exist. The error is: The name 'item' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @SanuelJackson I have no idea. An `IEnumerable<dynamic>` sounds like a *really* bad idea to me, let alone summing one of its properties.

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer` decoding a large JSON data set ( 6 MB ).  Wouldn't mind a fast way to convert the result reliably into a typed structure.  The Linq works on the first part of the enumerable, but sub-linq querying can not access the enumerator with this code.

Comment: @SanuelJackson How about using JsonSerializer from Newtonsoft.Json? Then its all strongly typed and LINQ works as expected.

Comment: I am aware of the Json projects out there and their pluses and pitfals.  I am using a class that was written by another SO user which works perfectly.  I am sure there is a way to access this data and query it and / or convert the data into a strong type.  I am not looking for another project just to suit that it resolves one issue :)

Comment: @SanuelJackson Fair enough. In case you aren't aware, Newtonsoft is used by pretty much the entire ASP.NET world. I would personally trust it over code I found on SO. Good luck with your dynamic objects though.

Comment: I am aware.  If curious, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3806407/3504007  is the deserialization I am using.